# How to drop one of any two highly correlated features having low correlation with target

Tags: python, machine-learning, scikit-learn, classification, feature-selection

I am working with the breast cancer dataset included in the [scikit-learn's](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer.html#sklearn.datasets.load_breast_cancer)  package, loaded like so:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import seaborn as sns
from sklearn.datasets import load_breast_cancer

data = load_breast_cancer()
df = pd.DataFrame(data.data, columns=data.feature_names)
df['target'] = data.target
df['target'] = df['target'].map({0:'malignant', 1:'benign'})
#data.head()
```

I can calculate and plot the the features correlation like so:

```py
corr_mat = df.corr()
mask = np.triu(np.ones_like(corr_mat, dtype=bool))
heatmap = sns.heatmap(corr_mat, vmin=-1, vmax=1, mask=mask, cmap='BrBG')
```

[image]

That said, suppose I set `abs(0.7)` as threshold to determine if features `i` and `j` are highly-correlated, so I can drop one of them. But then instead of dropping in any order, I want to make sure I drop the one with low correlation to the target variable `df['target']`.

Something like:

```py
for i in range(len(corr_mat.columns)):
    for j in range(i):
        if abs(corr_mat.iloc[i, j]) > 0.7:
        # if correlation of corr_mat.columns[i] to df['target'] < corr_mat.columns[j] to df['target']
        #     drop corr_mat.columns[i]
        # else drop corr_mat.columns[j]
```

Can someone help with this?

Answer (score 0):

You would want to calculate the correlation of that feature column with the target, and not correlation matrix. Something like this:

```
from IPython.core.display import deepcopy

features_list = list(corr_mat.keys())
to_keep = deepcopy(features_list)

for i in range(1,len(features_list)):
    k1 = features_list[i]
    for j in range(i):
        k2 = features_list[j]
        if(abs(corr_mat[k1][k2]) > 0.7):
            if((k2 in to_keep) and (k1 in to_keep)):
                c1 = df[k1].corr(df['target'])
                c2 = df[k2].corr(df['target'])
                if(c1>c2):
                    to_keep.remove(k2)
                else:
                    to_keep.remove(k1)
reduced = df[to_keep]
```